# Kotlin: Android application stop unexpectedly due to textView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

here is a simple code that i am running

```
class Second : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //val intent = intent.getStringExtra("textValue").toString()
        val text: TextView
        //text = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView // this statement
        //text.text = "New Text"
        setContentView(R.layout.second)
    }
}
```

and this is textView code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Activity!" />
```

now when i un comment the textView code the application stop working, and without those lines it works what may be the reason??

Comment: It should be `findViewById(R.id.textView)` instead of what you currently have.

Comment: move `setContentView` after `super.onCreate`

Comment: Use after : `setContentView()`.

Comment: It's not able to find the view that's why it's crashing. First use `setContentView()` so that layout gets set. Move `setContentView()` just below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: @WaqarHaider For future reference, please make sure to utilize stack traces from the logcat (it's there for a reason), and include the errors in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById` before your layout is set, move `setContentView` to the beginning of the function, like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.second)

    //val intent = intent.getStringExtra("textValue").toString()
    val text: TextView
    text = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView // this statement
    text.text = "New Text"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486219/kotlin-android-application-stop-unexpectedly-due-to-textview/44486280#comment75966497_44486219), move `setContentView` after `super.onCreate` otherwise there will be no `XML` layout attached to `activity` to find view plus you would want to call `setContentView` as soon as possible to reduce the layout initialization delay

```
class Second : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.second)
        // ^^^^^ should be called first to find view from layout
        //val intent = intent.getStringExtra("textValue").toString()
        val text: TextView
        text = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView // this statement
        text.text = "New Text"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Android widget instantiations/initializations after the layout is set, setContentView() in other words. Though I highly recommend that you use the [Kotlin Android Extensions plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to keep potential widget bugs and code minimal.